# subView in DetailViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uikit

I have a main table view and a detail view. when i click cell detail view should show the details of that item. now what i wanna do is to create subview and put that subview in detailView instead of creating a detailview for every cell. it ll solve my some other problems. Code looks like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    DetailViewController *nextController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];

    int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition:[indexPath length] -1];

    [nextController initWithObjectAtIndex:storyIndex inArray:stories];

    NSString *storyTitle = [[stories objectAtIndex:storyIndex] objectForKey:@"title"];

    nextController.title = @"Details";

    UIBarButtonItem *tempButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init] autorelease];
    tempButtonItem.title = @"Tillbaka";
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = tempButtonItem ;

       [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];

       [nextController release];
}
```

now how can i create a subview with a label and change text of that label to storyTitle.
thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can i create a subview with a label and change text of that label to storyTitle

Given a parent view, you don't need to create a new subview just to add a label to the parent.   But, assuming you really do want to add a subview with a label to your parent view, then do this:

```
...
UIView *parentView;
...
UIView *subView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:mySubViewFrame] autorelease];
UILabel *lbl = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:myLabelFrame] autorelease];
lbl.text = storyTitle;
[subView addSubview: lbl];
[parentView addSubview: subView];
```

Comment: infact in my app when one cell is clicked in table view its detailview  shows its details. and i have next and previous button on detailview. when i click on 3rd item. and on detailview when i click previous button it goes back to main table view. but it should go back to 2nd item's detailview. thats y i want to add subview so that my back button ll always go to main table view. and when i ll press next or previous view i ll just change the subview. do u think its a nice approach or is there some else better than that? thanx bro

Comment: I'm having a hard time following exactly what you're trying to do.   Sounds kind of non-standard, is there some reason you don't want to push a detail view controller instead when a cell is selected?

Comment: i did that before.everything was working fine except that when i click previous button,animation was still like its going to next cells details.butit was getting right cell information. to make animation like its going to previous cell i wrote these lines of code:   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:prevController animated:NO]; then animation was ok. but if i click 3rd cell, it shows its detailview. and if i click previous on that detail view, instead of going to 2nd item's details it goes to main table view.